# Flutter DropUp Button

Tags: flutter, dropdown, direction

I've searched But I cant find.
Is there something like **Drop Up Button** in Flutter ?

Or what I really need is a kinda message box that show up on `InkWell` info Button when user Tap on it.

This is on Web

[image: Something like this]

The message box **TICKET VIP CONCERT 4K** shows up when user clicks on **info** icon

Comment: could you please add some ui of what you want?

Comment: need ref image. Share a google image or something.

Comment: This is often called a tooltip or popup.

Comment: @hackape Thanks I found it. But the tooltip message only shows up on longPress. Is there a way to customize it so that it shows on simple Tap?

Comment: Never used flutter before, sorry can't help.